# Не получается написать логику взаимодействия между контроллерами

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть `viewController`. На него я поместил кнопку "Add Contact".
По нажатии  на неё происходит переход к адресной книге iPhone.
Общая логика такая:
`Add Contact` -> добавляем новый контакт -> переходим к списку контактов -> выбираем созданный контакт -> переходим к самой первой view, смотрим результат.
Но у меня пока что так:
`Add Contact` -> Переход к общему списку контактов -> Выбираем контакт -> Возвращаемся к `View` и видим результат.
Чтобы добавить новый контакт нужно вверху `view` нажать на "Back to Contacts", что не есть приемлемо.

Исходный код button Add Contact прилагаю:

```
- (IBAction)selectContact:(id)sender {


    CNContactPickerViewController *cvc = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc]init];
    [cvc setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:cvc animated:YES completion:nil];

    CNContactViewController * contactVC = [[CNContactViewController alloc]init];
    [contactVC setDelegate:self];
    [contactVC setAllowsActions:YES];
    [self presentViewController:contactVC animated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Какое может решение?
Спасибо.

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Мне нужен доступ к адресной книге, где можно вносить новые контакты.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html